# For what $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ is the equation $XA^T + B +\alpha X = 0$ not solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> For what $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ is equation $XA^T + B +\alpha X = 0$ not solvable, where $A$, $X$ and $B$ are matrices.
> $A$ and $B$ are not equal to zero.

My procedure: We can use commutativity of a scalar to get $XA^T + B +X\alpha  = 0$
Then we factor out $X$ :

$X(A^T + I\alpha)+ B = 0 $

To solve the equation the determinant of $(A^T + I\alpha)$ must be different from zero, so that we can find an inverse to right multiply and solve the equation.

Is my solution procedure correct or am I missing something ?

Comment: Are these matrices all square?

Comment: @MatthewPilling that info was not in the problem description, I think that they aren't neccessarily sqaure, but I don't know

Comment: Ok. Just remember you can only talk about determinants with square matrices.

Comment: The solvability of this equation also depends on your matrices $A$ and $B$. For example, if $\alpha=0$, then you can write your equation as $AX^T=-B^T$. If there exists a column of $-B^T$ that isn't contained in the column space of $A$, then $AX^T=-B^T$ doesn't have any solution.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Ok, but otherwise my solution is correct, right ? if $\alpha$ is not zero

Comment: @MatthewPilling Do you maybe know how we could solve this question if the matrices wouldn't be square and we couldn't use the determinant to check if it is invertible ?

Comment: You need $A$ to be square for $A+\alpha I$ to even be defined.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Is the procedure of my solution correct in that case?

Comment: This problem does not make sense. Given any $A,\alpha$ and any $X$, if we set $B=-XA^T-\alpha X$, the equation will be solvable. I think the problem setter probably intended to ask "given $A$, for what $\alpha$ is the equation not solvable for some $B$?" instead.

Comment: @user1551 I assumed the OP had $A$ and $B$ given, and we were trying to find all $\alpha$ so that this equation has no solution in $X$. But I don't know if this assumption is proper. You bring up a good point.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Your assumption is correct.